# c++ function to reverse string doesn't work

Tags: c++

Just learning c++. The following function is my attempt to reverse a string (doesn't work and I don't know why). Thank you for spotting my stupidity.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string r(string s)
{
    int len = s.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        char temp = s[i];
        s[i] = s[len - i];
        s[len - i] = temp; 
    }

    return s;
}

int main()
{
    cout << r("ASTRING");
}
```

It changes first letter of the string to `' '` and outputs  `STRING`

Comment: Work thru your reversal on paper, or in a debugger. Which elements get swapped on the first iteration of the loop? Which elements get swapped on the last?

Comment: hi, perhaps `s[len - i]` is out of bounds on the first iteration.

Comment: @IronMan I tried printing `s[len - i]` and it is not out of bounds. It prints last letter of the word

Comment: @Cool_Cornflakes [`std::reverse()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) already does that in a safe and robust way. Don't reinvent the wheel, especially not if it comes out as a square.

Comment: The problem is you go all the way through the string. You should stop at half way, otherwise you swap them all, then swap them all back whilst traversing the second half.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I am just trying to get familiar with c++. Just practicing .

Comment: I tried halving the number of iterations `for (int i = 0; i < len/2; i++)` and it almost works but not quite.

Comment: @Cool_Cornflakes To get familiar with c++, you should concentrate to learn about the facilities you can have from the standard library. That's more productive IMO. Also step through your code line by line with the debugger. You'll find the problem fairly fast.

Comment: @Cool_Cornflakes Stop at half way, or 1 char before the middle if length is odd.

Comment: Alright I will need to learn how to use debugger first for that. I will do that and get back to you guys if I still cant figure it out. Thanks for all the advice

Comment: @Cool_Cornflakes It's undefined behavior. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator[]/

Comment: That's a nice switcheroo you've got going on there :)

Comment: @pdm2011 Yes that fixed my problem. The first letter is still missing but that is probably because of what IronMan suggested, so I will look into that.

Comment: @Cool_Cornflakes, the question is: What's `s[len - i]` when `i` is 0?

Comment: @anastaciu Ahhh It just clicked. Thanks. I keep forgetting arrays start from 0

Comment: waht does  `s[len - 0]` mean? If this position exists?

Comment: off-by-one error, index of string is 0 to len-1. You must be using an old C++ compiler as all newer should have a \0 in the position len.

Comment: rhat code actually behaves funny.. if you print s[i] within loop at beginning and end, value changes, but after exit from loop it return to original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, `string.length()` returns length with `'\0'`  which mean end of string, so you need to delete 1.
Secondly, you don't travel whole string, you should stop at the middle, i/2 will just do this whatever the length is.

finally :

```cpp
string r(string s)
{
    int len = s.length() - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < len/2; i++)
    {
        char temp = s[i];
        s[i] = s[len - i];
        s[len - i] = temp;
    }

    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another simple way:

```cpp
string r(string s)
{
    int len = s.length();
    string temp;
    for (int i = len - 1; i > -1; i--)
    {
        temp.push_back(s[i]);
    }
    s = temp;
    return s; // or return temp;
}
```